# Swagger ... query-parameter properties access from Mustache

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using Mustache with swagger-codegen to generate model-entities from definitions, and code from operations (paths section). Each operation specifies a list of parameters, and other parameter attributes - datatype, description, default-value, required, maximum, example, etc.

I cannot work out how to access *any* parameter property besides the 'required' attribute ... except in the 'model' phase ... how can I do this in the 'api' phase ? ... I'd like to be able to drop code that verifies that the parameters meet conditions beyond 'required', like min/max, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have some options for accessing parameter properties.

First off, I assume you're using swagger-codegen 2.1.0-M2 or a later snapshot.  There are a number of properties available for each parameter, but they are currently not quite as rich as in the model properties.

To see what you have access to, please run the codegen with debug flags, which will print out all the information available to you in the templates:

```
java -DdebugOperations -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
      generate \
     -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
     -l java \
     -o samples/client/petstore/java
```

The other debug flags are:

```
# print out the interpreted swagger spec
-DdebugSwagger

# print out model info
-DdebugModels

# print out supporting file data
-DdebugSupportingFiles
```

Comment: I'm running codegen 2.1.1-M1. I can see from the 'debugOpertations' that the only property listed that is interesting in my case is the 'required' property. But not the value-constraints. I have no problem accessing and using these value-constraints in the model phase, just need to know if I can get access to them in the operation phase, but looks like not. Has anyone else asked for this ? ... my use-case is that, when generating code for operations, I would like to be able to validate the 'outbound' parameters from my client using those value-constraints.